# Multi-device hybrid apps: How to do combine, minify and obfuscate in release and distribution build process?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Is there a good way to combine Javascript/Css files and do minification and obfuscation for the release and distribution builds using the multi-device hybrid apps project type for Visual Studio? I currently use Grunt for executing these tasks, but I'm interested in a complete Visual Studio driven process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-device hybrid apps: combining Grunt and msbuild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276099/multi-device-hybrid-apps-combining-grunt-and-msbuild)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Grunt/gulp with the [TaskRunner Explorer extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708) for Visual Studio.

To make sure your application will exclude the node_modules directory when you'll build it, you'll have to edit the util.js file in c:\Users_user_name_\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\lib\ like this :

```
util.getDefaultFileNameEndingExclusions = function () {
    return [settings.projectSourceDir + '/bin',
            settings.projectSourceDir + '/bld',
            settings.projectSourceDir + '/node_modules',//add this line
            settings.projectSourceDir + '/merges',
            settings.projectSourceDir + '/plugins',
            settings.projectSourceDir + '/res',
            settings.projectSourceDir + '/test',
            settings.projectSourceDir + '/tests',
            '.jsproj', '.jsproj.user'];
}
```

This extension provides a grunt/gulp task control panel in visual studio :
[image]

Install your npm modules will be the only thing you will have to do out of Visual Studio

Hope that helps